# Discontinuity and Differentiable Functions

Tags: real-analysis, continuity

Given the function $f(x) = x^2$ if $x$ is a rational number and $f(x) = 0$  otherwise, prove that $f$ is differentiable at $0$, but discontinuous at all points except $ \\0$.

I have the first part where I show that is it differentiable at$\ \ 0$. However, how do I go about showing that is is discontinuous everywhere but $ \ \ 0$ by using to sequences that will converge to different limits?

Answer (score 3):

Fix any point $x\neq 0$, and distinguish two cases.

If $x\in\mathbb{Q}$, $f(x) > 0$; however, in any neighborhood of $x$, no matter how small, there is going to be an irrational $r$, for which $f(r)=0$. So that, by taking $\varepsilon = \frac{f(x)}{2}$, you get
$$ \exists \varepsilon > 0, \forall \delta > 0, \exists r_\delta\in(x-\delta,x+\delta)\text{ s.t. } |f(x)-f(r_\delta)|=f(x) > \varepsilon$$

Similarly if $x\notin\mathbb{Q}$; then, take $\varepsilon = \frac{x^2}{2}$, and similarly there will be in any neighborhood of $x$ a rational $q$ for which $f(q)=q^2 > \frac{x^2}{2}$: that is,
$$ \exists \varepsilon > 0, \forall \delta > 0, \exists q_\delta\in(x-\delta,x+\delta)\text{ s.t. } |f(x)-f(q_\delta)|=f(q_\delta)=q_\delta^2 > \varepsilon$$

showing that (in both cases) $f$ is not continuous at $x$.

Answer (score 2):

Try showing that $\lim\limits_{x \to 0} f(x)=f(0)=0$, and so f is continuous at 0, but $\lim\limits_{x \to a} f(x) \neq f(a)$ for all $a \neq 0$. First, show that every real number is the limit of a sequence of rational numbers. Then show that for any $a\neq 0$ you can write a sequence $(a_n)_{n=1}^\infty$ that converges to $a$, such that $f(a) \neq \lim\limits_{n\to\infty} f(a_n)$.

Comment: You can obtain $\to$ using `\to`

Comment: Also, note the difference between $\lim\limits_{n\to\infty}$ `\lim\limits_{n\to\infty}` and $\lim_{n\to\infty}$ `\lim_{n\to\infty}`.

Comment: The goal is not actually to show that $\lim\limits_{x\to a}f(x)\neq f(a)$ for $a\neq 0$, it is to show that $\lim\limits_{x\to a}f(x) =f(a)$ is false for $a\neq 0$.  The limit does not exist, so it cannot be equal or unequal to something.

Comment: @JonasMeyer you're correct, that was an abuse of notation.