# How to show that $f$ is differentiable at $x=0.$

Tags: real-analysis

$f:\mathbb{R} \to  \mathbb{R}$ be defined as  $f(x)$= $x^2 , x \in \mathbb{Q} \\ 0 \ \ , x \in \mathbb{Q^c}\\ $

How to show that $f$ is differentiable at $x=0.$

I want to try this approach.

here  $f'(x)=$ $2x  \in \mathbb{Q}  \\
 0  \in \mathbb{Q^c} $

since $lt \\ x \to 0+$$f(x)$ = $lt \\ x \to 0-$$f(x)= 0$

so $f$ is differentiable at $x=0$

Comment: It's differentiable at $x = 0$, but since it's not differentiable anywhere else, what is "continuously differentiable" supposed to mean?

Comment: Are you sure that's true? For it to be continuously differentiable, $f'(x)$ needs to be defined in some neighborhood of $0$, and I don't think it is.

Comment: I think he meant "continuous and differentiable at $0$", which is (indeed) not the same thing.

Comment: @DanielFischer A function is said to be continuously differentiable if it has a derivative that itself is continuous.

Comment: I'm sorry - I should know this: what set is $\mathbb{Q^c}$ exactly? It doesn't ring a bell.

Comment: @EuroMicelli  I want to define $ \mathbb{Q^c}$ as $\mathbb{R} - \mathbb{Q} $

Answer (score 3):

You can't just apply the derivative rules unless you check differentiability. In fact in this case the function is only continuous at $x=0$ so this function could only be differentiable at $x=0$ if it is anywhere differentiable. We check if it is as follows.

We wish to find $\lim_{h\to0}\frac{f(0+h)-f(0)}{h}=\lim_{h\to0}\frac{f(h)}{h}$.

If $h\in\mathbb{Q}$ then we get $\frac{f(h)}{h}=\frac{h^{2}}{h}=h$.

If $h\in\mathbb{Q}^{c}$ then we get $\frac{f(h)}{h}=0$.

By choosing $|h|<\epsilon$ and looking at the above we have that $|\frac{f(h)}{h}-0|=|\frac{f(h)}{h}|\le|h|<\epsilon$.

Thus the derivative exists and is $0$ at $x=0$.

Answer (score 2):

If it is a homework, please specify it in the tags and state what you have tried. As a first observation and as Daniel Fischer and Thomas Andrews pointed out in the comments, the way your question is phrased, it is false: *continuously differentiable* at a point $x_0$ means *differentiable on a neighborhood of that point, with the derivative being continuous on this neighborhood*. In your case, $f$ is only differentiable (and even continuous) at $0$, and nowhere else.

Assuming you meant "continuous and differentiable at $0$":

- for the continuity, show that for any $\epsilon > 0$, there exists a $\delta > 0$ (here, try $\delta = \sqrt\epsilon$, for instance) such that $|x-0| \leq \delta\Rightarrow |f(x)-f(0)| \leq \epsilon$ (a distinction of two cases will do the trick).
- For differentiability, same thing ; use the definition of differentiability at a point.

PS: you also might want to have a look at [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/440098/discontinuity-and-differentiable-functions/440102#440102).

---

Edit: regarding your approach; you're not *allowed* to write "$f'(x)=2x$ for $x\in\mathbb Q$"; $f$ is not continuous at any point except $0$, a fortiori it is not differentiable and its derivative is not defined.

Comment: @clement.c , nice help, thanks.
but I want to know is there any mistake in my approach?

Comment: @ROBINSON See my latest edit.

Comment: What kind of questions here are not homework? People aren't going to be solving basic real analysis questions for a job, are they?